# Transferring large amounts of data between windows components

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, uwp, blob

I am working on a Windows app using javascript as the UI. We are delegating a heavy processing task to a c++ component in order to increase performance. Unfortunately we have to transfer a large amount of JSON data between our c++ component to the javascript (like length 100000+ length arrays of objects) and I'm not sure the best way to do this. Our app is looking to perform this computation multiple times per second. Truth be told I don't actually know what is going on behind the scenes when data gets passed between javascript and c++.

One approach that I'm considering is to stringify the JSON, and pass that string through to the javascript before parsing. I haven't done any testing on that, but I'm afraid that it would be quite slow. As I mentioned above I don't know how/if the long string length would affect data transfer, and what the stringify and parse impact would be.

Another approach that I have considered is to essentially store the data as a blob, and pass the address to the javascript which could read the data from the blob. However I find the Windows documentation a little sparse/difficult to search (I'm a c++ rookie) and I don't know how I would accomplish that.

What I'm looking for is advice as to which method sounds better (and I'm open to other suggestions!) and/or help as to how to accomplish method 2. Thanks for your time!

Comment: What will you do to the data in JavaScript side? I mean, even if you are succeeded to transfer the data quickly, I guess it need time to handle/process it with JavaScript.

Comment: Implementation is still a little up in the air, but the c++ is being used to transform depth data from a 3D scanner to potentially a half-edge mesh, which will then be displayed using webgl. Ideally this would all be in c++, but we're trying it using JS because that's what we're comfortable with. Are you thinking that any time needed to transfer the data will be negligible compared to the JS processing?

Comment: Yes. But, if you use JSON (or other data serialization formats), it will introduce unnecessary, time consuming serialization-deserialization process. You should wrap the array inside an object then pass the object to JavaScript. Take a look at [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-basic-windows-runtime-component-in-cpp-and-calling-it-from-javascript-or-csharp) which shows how to pass array from C++ to JavaScript.